# Extracting Database content and display it on a page of a website

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I am developing a piece of code that allow me to extract the content of a database and display it on a page web . I am developping using vb.net and sql server 2008 .

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        ' Declare the query string.
        Dim queryString As String = _
          "Select [id], [username], [password] From [userTD]"

        ' Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet
        ' to the GridView control.
        Dim ds As DataSet = GetData(queryString)
        If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then

            AuthorsGridView.DataSource = ds
            AuthorsGridView.DataBind()

        Else

            ' Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database."
            Response.Write("<br>Unable to connect to the database.")

        End If

    End If

End Sub

Function GetData(ByVal queryString As String) As DataSet


    ' Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
    Dim connectionString As String
    connectionString = ("Data Source=mypc-PC;Database=mytempDB;Integrated Security=true ")

    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Try

        ' Connect to the database and run the query.
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection)

        ' Fill the DataSet.
        adapter.Fill(ds)


    Catch ex As Exception

        ' The connection failed. Display an error message.
        ' Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database."
        Response.Write("<br>Unable to connect to the database.")
    End Try

    Return ds

End Function
End Class
```

The code works fine .
In my case I have to declare "AuthorsGridView " in default.aspx but my goal is to display data without modifying default.aspx .

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.  _Especially_ do not display passwords, ever.

Comment: You mean that you would like to display result of the query, but you don't want to alter ASPX markup by adding the GridView?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes , this is what I want but I didn't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have the gridview defined and you cannot alter ASPX markup, you have multiple other options here, just a few of them

- You can create GridView control programmatically and add it page controls collection
- You can build ASP.NET Table in code and populate its cells with data
- You can build your HTML with output using StringBuilder and then output the results

If you do need to  declare "AuthorsGridView" gridview - the first option is for you.

As the very basic example (you may need to adjust it, add/modify gridview properties) replace lines

```
AuthorsGridView.DataSource = ds
AuthorsGridView.DataBind()
```

with

```
Dim AuthorsGridView As New GridView

With AuthorsGridView
    .ID = "AuthorsGridView"
    .Width = Unit.Pixel(500)
    .AutoGenerateColumns = True
    .DataSource = ds
    .DataBind()
End With

Me.Form.Controls.Add(AuthorsGridView)
```

Comment: I am a new with asp.net ,please may you explain me more ?

Comment: I get this error "Control 'AuthorsGridView' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated last line, it should be `Me.Form.Controls.Add(AuthorsGridView)`

Comment: I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: You marked this as answered, does it mean it worked for you? If not - which line is causing error?

Comment: The last line Me.Form.Controls.Add(AuthorsGridView)

Comment: Did you copy code exactly as above indicated? Placed as it is in Page_Load event it should not cause that error.
Also can you verify that your ASPX page does have a `Form` tag with `runat="server"` attribute?

Comment: I didn't have Form tag with runat="server" attribute . I add it and works like a charm .